# How to stop Manipulate with PolarPlot from resizing PolarAxes?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm having some difficulty figuring out why the following code resizes the polar axes once move the slider past a certain number.

```
Manipulate[
 PolarPlot[{3 Cos[2 th]}, {th, 0, i}, PolarAxes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> 5], {i, .001, 2 Pi}]
```

Here is gif showing the resizing.

[image]

How can I stop it from resizing?  I know it's something simple, but have tried everything I can think of. Tried PlotRangeClipping option, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With[{n = 5},
 Manipulate[
  PolarPlot[{3 Cos[2 th]}, {th, 0, i}
   , PolarAxes -> True
   , PolarAxesOrigin -> {π/2, n}
   , PlotRange -> n
   , PolarTicks -> {Range[0, 2 π - π/6, π/6], Range[1, n]}
   , PolarGridLines -> {Range[0, 2 π, π/6], Range[1, n]}
   , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}}
   , PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15]
   , Frame -> False
   , Axes -> False
   ]
  , {i, .01, 2 π}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`PlotRange -> Full` works fine with me

```
Manipulate[
 PolarPlot[{3 Cos[2 th]}, {th, 0, i},
  PlotRangePadding -> 1.5,
  PolarAxes -> True,
  PlotRange -> Full],
 {i, .001, 2 Pi}]
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir.  I love this site.

Comment: Actually still have a problem.  Now the radial distances get resized.  See the vertical line up the middle on the circle.

Comment: I have added `PlotRangePadding -> 1.5`. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: It still jumps for some reason from a length of 4 to 5 units.